# Class not found in a CakePHP shell script

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to include some classes in my shell script in CakePHP but they don't seem to load.

For example I have a class located in

```
/app/Lib/php-ews/EWSType/FindItemType.php
```

My script looks like this :

```
App::uses('FindItemType', 'Lib/php-ews/EWSType');

class TestShell extends AppShell {  

    public function main() {
        $this->out($this->readbox());
    }

    public function readbox() {
        $request = new EWSType_FindItemType();
    }
}
```

This gives an error:

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'EWSType_FindItemType' not found in "
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Exchange Web Services should be installed in the `Vendor` folder and loaded via `App::import()`.

From the CakePHP 2.x [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files):

> Your vendor files may not follow conventions, have a class that differs from the file name or does not contain classes. You can load those files using `App::import()`.

In your case:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'FindItemType', array('file' => 'php-ews/EWSType/FindItemType.php'));
```